# Navigation Controller can not been embedded in

Tags: storyboard, navigationcontroller, xcode13.3

I have been using XCode Version 13.3 (13E113)for 3 months. Had no any problem about it but today when I tried to add navigation controller, I encountered the following situation (Picture 1).

[Picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IV1zx.png)

When I try to arrange view, this happens. (Picture 2)

[Picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nyce4.png)

And when I try to delete navigation controller, Xcode is closed by itself. I was using this XCode until now and I added navigation controller many times. I do not know what happens. I deleted XCode and load again. But nothing changed.

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I do not why but it is a bug. It is not resolved by deleting and uploading again XCode.

This method worked for me. Add navigation controller and then open main.storyboard as source code. Do nothing and open it again as interface builder. It's done. I have no any idea how.

Have a good day.